# Submit button on html service called Google form not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

This function in a google sheet does popup a window with the form, but the submit button is dead. What is missing that will make this window a live one?

```
function launchForm() {
  var formID = '1YznrnFFIfXLpsZfsIZ4xjhlwmi8eLv_nTuOjDKGhwIc';
  var form = FormApp.openById(formID);
  var formUrl = form.getPublishedUrl();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formUrl);
  var formHtml = response.getContentText();

  var htmlApp = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutput(formHtml)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Ta Daaa!')
      .setWidth(500)
      .setHeight(650);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlApp, 'Query window');
}
```

The function is hooked to a menu item and clicking on that item does bring up the form over the sheet, as does running the script from the script project attached to the sheet.

```
menuEntries.push({name: "Launch Query form", functionName: "launchForm"});
```

This particular form is simple, only three fields.  So I could consider using HTML service to build an HTML  and I see lots of questions about that not working either, so I can probably work that out.  However, I have other forms that are a lot more complex and being able to simply call a regular Google form from within the spreadsheet is what I'd rather do.

Comment: There is a similar question that says it's not quite possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327256/google-apps-script-display-form-in-sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the URL of the Google Form into the HTML of the dialog box:

### Code.gs

```
function launchForm() {

  var htmlApp = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutputFromFile('InputForm')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Ta Daaa!')
      .setWidth(500)
      .setHeight(650);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlApp, 'Query window');
}
```

### InputForm.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/FormIDHere/viewform?embedded=true" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

In "New" Google Forms you can get the IFRAME tag to embed the Google Form by clicking the "Send" button at the top right, and then clicking the third tab "<>"

Comment: I like the iframe usage, it worked fine.  Now, how can I close it after submit is done, rather than needing the user to click the x.  Or, alternatively, show a close button also on the form.  (workaround will be to put more instructions in the form).

Comment: Good question.  I'm not sure, but you might be able to add an onsubmit event handler to the IFRAME tag?  `<iframe  onsubmit="google.script.host.close()" src="url"</iframe>`